# Custom ListView control will not paint when first shown

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, ownerdrawn

I have created a custom ListView control to suit my needs and I'm having an issue that causes the ListView not to show any contents (not drawing anything, just white) when the form first loads.

If I resize the form or click on my control (anything that forces a repaint on the ListView) then it shows up as expected.

As a side note, it used to work just fine until I made a small change today and rebuilt the control.  I removed all the changes I made and rebuilt again but the issue still happens.  Any ideas as to why it will not show up (paint) when the form is first loaded?

This is what I use to do the custom drawing on my custom ListView control...

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = e.Item.ImageList.Images[e.Item.ImageIndex];
    Size textSize = new Size((int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(e.Item.Text, e.Item.Font).Width, (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString(e.Item.Text, e.Item.Font).Height);

    //Get the area of the item to be painted
    Rectangle bounds = e.Bounds;
    bounds.X = 0;
    bounds.Width = this.Width;

    //Set the spacing on the list view items
    int hPadding = 0;
    int vPadding = 0;
    IntPtr padding = (IntPtr)(int)(((ushort)(hPadding + bounds.Width)) | (uint)((vPadding + bounds.Height) << 16));
    SendMessage(this.Handle, (uint)ListViewMessage.LVM_SETICONSPACING, IntPtr.Zero, padding);

    //Set the positions of the image and text
    int imageLeft = (bounds.Width / 2) - (image.Width / 2);
    int imageTop = bounds.Top + 3;
    int textLeft = (bounds.Width / 2) - (textSize.Width / 2);
    int textTop = imageTop + image.Height;
    Point imagePosition = new Point(imageLeft, imageTop);
    Point textPosition = new Point(textLeft, textTop);

    //Draw background
    using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(e.Item.BackColor))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, bounds);

    //Draw selected
    if (e.Item.Selected)
    {
        using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(m_SelectedColor))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, bounds);
    }

    //Draw image
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, imagePosition);

    //Draw text
    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Item.Text, e.Item.Font, new SolidBrush(e.Item.ForeColor), textPosition);
}
```

I also set the following things in the Constructor of my custom control...

```
public MyListView()
{
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    this.OwnerDraw = true;
    this.View = View.LargeIcon;
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Hand;
    this.Scrollable = false;
}
```

I also inherit the ListView class...

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    //All my source
}
```

Comment: Does it hapen to sit in a tabpage that is not visible at first? Also: are you sure OnDrawItem isn't called or does it maybe just not work as expected at first? (Set a breakpoint!)

Comment: I have it directly on a form.  I used to use the tab control but had issues with it so I ran away from that direction.  How can I tell if OnDrawItem is "called"?  I'm thinking it might not just work as expected at the first draw...  I just can't figure out why.  If the SAME code works perfect after the control is shown then why not the very first draw?

Comment: As a matter of fact I think the OnDrawItem is not even firing for some reason until I do something like force a resize etc..

Comment: _How can I tell if OnDrawItem is "called"?_ Well, set a breakpoint to it and observe when it is called for the first time. Also watch the call stack when the break point gets hit.. You may want to scim over the desiger.cs file to look for dubious lines there. Hard to tell from here, of course.

Comment: My custom control is a separate dll.  I forget how to step through another project's dll source while debugging an exe using that dll...

Comment: Scratch that, I just needed to make sure my dll was building in debug and not release so it was generating the *.pdb file for the dll.  Now the breakpoint works perfectly!  - Thanks

Comment: Good; but it brings you back to square one, doesn't it? Not sure what to advise now, though..

Comment: As far as the OnDrawItem getting hit, yet it does 4 times (the number of items in the list) just as it gets hit 4 times when I resize the form and it works then...  Looking at the designer.cs code everything looks normal.  :/  - Not sure what to at this point..

Comment: Hm, sounds strange. So it gets hit and runs through but it doesn't show??

Comment: Correct, now at this point I'm thinking it has to be getting painted over with a solid white brush or something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129587/discussion-between-arvo-bowen-and-taw).

Comment: I tried to render the listview using your code but the output was not acceptable at all regardless of `View`property value. It doesn't act like you described. even after resize and refresh the rendered content was unacceptable. It's better to share all of code. Then more help can be shared.

Comment: This "custom control" is not meant to look like a normal listview.  I have a lot of preset properties and hide a bunch as well.  So, the "rendered content" you're talking about in not in question.  Just the fact it would render it to start with is.  With all that said...  I'm updating my original question to include the only other things that have to do with rendering at all.

Comment: Also, After using large icon view you need to add a few icons with text.  I use 48x48 images from an imagelist.  The icons end up stacking vertically and form a 1 column list of icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the set the control to redraw itself when resized. So add this code in constructor of your control:

```
this.ResizeRedraw = true;
```

[image]

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/TYmAkf0S) is the exact code which is used to create the control. (WIN8.1 - .NET4.5 - VS2013.4)

Comment: So after much headache and time I found that I had absolutely nothing wrong with my control.  It was your answer that made me create another control just like my existing one and test it.  To my surprise it worked great.  I simply copied my existing non-working control and pasted it on the form and then new one worked!  Sometimes VS just does weird things...  Somehow I managed to muck up the control's creation object or something...

Comment: In fact your code worked for me when showing the form. But when resizing it was not working, so I added `this.ResizeRedraw = true;` which fixed sizing issue.

Comment: Also, apparently something else might have been the issue too...  Try this with your test project...  Set the dock prop on it to LEFT, THEN add a panel and set it to dock FULL so you have the ListView on the left and the panel on the right.  As soon as I do that (making sure the ListView is sent to the back) that's when I see the issue again.  Well at least I know what NOT to do now...

Comment: I created the layout. After startup, there was no problem. Just when sizing the `ListView` using a `Splitter` which I put between `Panel` and `ListView` it needs `ResizeRedraw = true;` otherwise the content of `ListView` doesn't refresh.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies:
Doing the below reset my event handlers and the problem went away. However, once I hooked them up, I found the Resize event handler that I used to set the ColumnWidth was causing the issue. Why setting the ColumnWidth is causing this, I do not know.

<s>Arvo Bowen's comment on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40924226/9300908) fixed it for me also (.NET 4.8 Framework, VS2022). To be clear, not requiring `this.ResizeRedraw = true;` from the answer.</s>

> So after much headache and time I found that I had absolutely nothing wrong with my control. It was your answer that made me create another control just like my existing one and test it. To my surprise it worked great. I simply copied my existing non-working control and pasted it on the form and then new one worked! Sometimes VS just does weird things... Somehow I managed to muck up the control's creation object or something..